# Al actualizar Rider no consigo compilar: no se encontró: "CL.exe". El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Estoy intentando compilar una DLL, pero después de actualizar el IDE Rider a la última versión, no consigo compilar obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
No se encontró: "CL.exe". El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
```

He reparado Visual Studio 2022 desde el instalador.

También Visual Studio Build Tools 2022.

También he reinstalado Rider.

Me ocurre con esa DLL y si creo una nueva también, por lo que el error es general para todos los proyectos.

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

He desinstalado completamente Visual Studio 2022 y vuelto a instalar

Ha funcionado, ahora puedo compilar sin problemas desde Visual Studio 2022 y desde Jetbrains Rider